# turning CSV string[] into string[][]

Tags: java, csv

I have turned a grid into a CSV format, which turns it into a string in order to save the grid.

However, when I want to open the CSV file, I have to turn the string back into a 2D array.. I have tried to work out how to do it, but I am unsure on how to join the two `string[]` so that it turns into a 2D array.

I added an `;` where the line ends and a new line must begin, but I am confused about how to add it together.

The code:

```
public static void open() {
            // The name of the file to open.
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter the name of the file you wish to open: ");
            String fileName = name+ ".txt";

            // This will reference one line at a time
            String line = null;

            char gridWorld[][];

            try {
                // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

                // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                String[] firstsplit, secondsplit;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
                        firstsplit = line.split(";");   // if semi colon, replace with new line

                    }

                    secondsplit = line.split(","); // splitting the line in columns

                }

                // Always close files.
                bufferedReader.close();
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The .csv file format with line# and indices:

```
       | columnIndex
       | 1 2 3 4 
----------------
line1  | 1,2,3,4
line2  | 5,6,7,8
line3  | 9,a,b,c
...
lineN  | w,x,y,z
```

With this visualization it should be easy to see how to parse it. Here is a code snippet to read it into your `gridWorld` array, hope this helps:

```
lineIndex = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] split = line.split(",");
    for (int i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
        gridWorld[lineIndex][i] = split[i].charAt(0);        
    }
    lineIndex++;
}
```

Comment: I get the error..'Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char' on the split[i] bit..

Comment: This would require you to know the size of your grid to start with when initialising `gridWorld`

Comment: yes, in this case I am assuming a well-formed .csv file with known dimensions

Answer (score 0):

If your input csv file is in the misformed

```
words,things,stuff;more words, more stuff, more things
line2 words,line2 stuff,line2 things;
```

So there are multiple lines in the file with `;` in the lines which you want to separate into different lines also so that your output would be

```
words,things,stuff
more words,more stuff, more things
line2 words,line2 stuff,line2 things
```

What you will need to do is read each line first and splitting it by `;` holding these in memory. The below approach will also mean that you will not need to know the size of your grid in advance

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
{
    String[] split1 = line.split(";");
    for( String s1 : split1)
        al.add(s1);
}

String[][] gridWorld = new String[al.size()][];

for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
{
    gridWorld[i] = al.get(i).split(",");
}
```

And this can all be reduced to this

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    al.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(";")));

String[][] gridWorld = new String[al.size()][];

for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
    gridWorld[i] = al.get(i).split(",");
```